# Office 2007 Installation Fails with MSI Error 2203

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, windows-installer

I'm installing Office 2007 (or any of the individual Office 2007 products) on a clean Vista SP2 machine and installer is failing with error 2203: "An internal error has occurred. c:\windows\installer\4dd58d1.msi -2147287035)..."  (Note that the 4dd58d1.msi filename is just an example here - it may be different on different instances of the install process.)

Googling for error 2203 gives results relating to read-only/permission problems with the msi source files but I've verified this is not the case.

Have tried multiple Office 2007 install sources and same result.

Thoughts?

Comment: Tried running the installers as administrator?

Comment: Which version of vista?

Comment: @John T - I have.  Both native as admin and with runas.
@Troggy - Vista Ultimate SP2.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7:

1. Run `%TEMP%` then temporary folder will open.
2. Go up one level and right click on TEMP folder
3. Take Ownership of the folder.
4. Now Windows 7 will allow to install Office 2007 and other 3rd party software too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off UAC? This has caused a number of installing issues for me previously.

EDIT: Where are you running your install from (CD/Local Drive/Network Drive)? Do you have full access to this location?

Comment: hi Craig I did indeed.  I actually turned off UAC immediately upon building the machine.

Comment: This may sound odd but try turning UAC on again. There have been a few issues with software failing to install if UAC is turned off. This really shouldn't affect Office but it can't hurt to try

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from this [article](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=6933111#post6933111) :

> I recently had this problem installing
>   third party software. 
> Some software
>   uses the `c:\documents and settings\%username%\local settings\temp` folder to store files temporarily
>   during install. 
> I checked the
>   permissions on this, set them to
>   'full' for my account and system, and
>   everything went ok.

Answer (score 1):

It's a permissions error on one of the windows folders. I tried permissions changes to %temp% and /Windows/Installers but the problem only went away when I did a Windows Refresh on my (new) Windows 8 gigabyte laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start installation under administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an antivirus product installed? Some have the option to block installations from the Temp directory. The MSIs will expand there first before install.

Comment: Hi Mark - I do (AVG Free).  I tried with antivirus on then off.  Ultimately I was successful however there was no rhyme or reason to it that I could tell.