# Error 2203 when installing Python/Perl?

Tags: python, installer, windows-8-preview

I can't install Python or Strawberry Perl on the Windows 8 Developer Preview :( I keep getting installer error 2203; here's a link to the LOG file: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=SJ8BDNLV I really don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers here are from Mysterio, Harrymc and others are just a few of the many that state take ownership these range from permissions in temp folder not being set to 'system' or at least open and install as administrator or 'runas'.
 This also works for third party 'error 2203' from win7, XP and there is the likelihood that the same is true for Win 8.
[Office 2007 Installation Fails with MSI Error 2203](https://superuser.com/questions/26191/office-2007-installation-fails-with-msi-error-2203)
 I have not tried it on Win 8, but it does look like an ownership matter, most of the 'error 2203' where almost always installer related.
[Install Python for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/46961/install-python-for-windows)
One came down to damaged ram, i hope this is not so in your case.
 If this doesn;t work you may find your answer by typing 'error 2203' into search and tap enter.   There is not much on this subject in the Python Communities at the moment.
http://python.org/
hope this helps in someway.

Comment: It turned out I had two problems. One, my TEMP folder was on my desktop for some reason :/ after moving it, the install *almost* completed. then I followed the instructions at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/cannot-install-any-new-programs-start-menu-has/8aa1eb74-532c-42de-8b99-bde8c7d43270 and all went well. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem is access to default %temp% folder in your profile**

Ok, this has to do with access to your temp file location.  As with many, the temp folder permissions get jacked up with spyware/adware etc...

**Workaround**
open a command prompt (cmd.exe) (with admin permissions if not logged on as admin)

1. create a new folder for the installers and copy install files to a folder
   c:>md c:\installers
   c:>cd c:\installers

copy the msi files there, with explorer or command line

2. make a new directory: Example:
   md c:\temp
3. set the temp folder location to the new temp folder
   set temp=c:\temp
4. type the installer .msi in the command line

python-2.6.6.msi

and press enter

That should fix the install problem, but for the problem with the %temp% folder, use spy or adware remover and virus scanner, or just create a new profile.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer as administrator fix the problem for me

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: right-click on python.exe installer and click on run-as-administrator and continue the install normally.